# Convert musics to guitar chords or piano notes

Tags: conversion, music

Is there software that let's you convert your mp3s to guitar chords or piano notes?

Answer (score 1):

In a word, "No".

It's much too complex a problem at this time.

Comment: Right, if you poke around here and on Stack Overflow you can find a few questions where people talk about what *can* be done and what *might* be possible. Short answer: a lot (but still not everything) can be accomplished in rigidly controlled environments; rather less in the real world.